# How to access drawer from another activity

Tags: java, android

Here is my drawerActivity

```
public  class  DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    public static DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    public NavigationView navigationView;
    public Context mContext;
    private TextView empname, businame;
    private ImageView busiimg;
    private String[] drawerItem;


    public NavigationView getNavigationView() {
        return navigationView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = DrawerActivity.this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
         drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer, null);
        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
        super.setContentView(drawerLayout);
        initToolbar();
    }

    public void initToolbar() {
        try{
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("Manage vendor");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void setUpNav() {      
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_container);
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(DrawerActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_main);
         drawerToggle.syncState();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpNav();
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

  /*  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static void openDrawer(){
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I am accessing drawer when image clicked in another activity

```
 drawerImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DrawerActivity.openDrawer();
                }
            });
```

I am implementing navigation drawer in my android application. I have a separate activity for navigation drawer. I will extend the drawer activity where ever I want.

Now the issue is I have drawer image in bottom bar. When I click the image in bottom app bar I have to open the drawer. For one activity I want to open drawer by clicking the image in bottom bar. I know if I extend the drawer activity the hamburger icon will visible in toolbar that I don't want to achieve in this activity.

So how to avoid this scenario by using bottom bar?

Comment: "i will extend the drawer activity where ever i want" – If the `Activity` that contains `drawerImg` does indeed extend `DrawerActivity`, then nothing needs to be `static`. Aside from that, what exact issue are you having? Also, please use punctuation. Your description is nigh unintelligible.

Comment: That didn't really clarify anything. "i know if i extend the drawer activity the hamburger icon will visible in toolbar that i don't want to achieve in this activity." – So, the `Activity` that contains `drawerImg` does _not_ extend `DrawerActivity`? Why are you showing us `DrawerActivity`, then, and why are you trying to close its drawer? Doesn't the `Activity` that contains `drawerImg` have its own `DrawerLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Extend your draweractivity to your other activity.
try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends DrawerActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

         drawerImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    openDrawer();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to hide hamburger icon in toolbat

Comment: i don't want that hamburger icon in toolbar because i have hamburger image in bottom bar i want open drawer when image is clicked

Comment: use this for hide hamburger icon **drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);**

Answer (score 0):

Try implementating an interface.
Create an interface where you want to access the drawer activity.

```
public interface OnDrawerListener{
void onDrawerClick();
}
OnDrawerListener onDrawerListener;



drawerImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onDrawerListener.onDrawerClick();
                }
            });
```

Then implement this interface in your DrawerActivity.

```
  public  class  DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InterfaceActivity.OnDrawerListener{ //InterfaceActivity is activity where you have created your interface.



     private InterfaceActivity.OnDrawerListener someInterface;

              @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    someInterface = (InterfaceActivity.OnDrawerListener) this;

        }
//Your interface override

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClick(){
    openDrawer();
    }
            }
```